# Firefox Add-on : Where to specify new version number

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, version, firefox-addon-sdk

I am creating a firefox add-on using the addon-sdk-1.17. I submitted version 0.1 for review, which passed. Now I've made some changes to the add-on. Under my submissions, when I clicked on "Upload new version" and uploaded the xpi, I got a message saying "Version 0.1 already exists". Do I have to specify the version number in my project somewhere?

Comment: `package.json` i think

Comment: Thanks for verificaiton @LM10 so package.json was right place?

Comment: Yes it was. The entire manifest of the add-on was in package.json. I can't believe I didn't check it. Thank you @Noitidart.

Comment: Cool thanks for the double verify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Noitidart mentioned, for the Firefox Add-on SDK, the version of the add-on is contained in the [*package.json*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json) file.

The property/key [`version`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json#Key_reference) will define the version for the add-on.  For your add-on the line:

```
"version": "0.1",
```

will need to be changed to something like:

```
"version": "0.2",
```

or

```
"version": "0.1.1",
```

or any other `version` number.

**Version number format:**
Version numbers must comply with the rules in "[Extension Versioning, Update and Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extension_Versioning,_Update_and_Compatibility)" which basically says that it should comply with "[Toolkit version format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Toolkit_version_format)".  That page says that a version is a string made up of *version parts* separated by a `.`. A *version part* is a sequence of four portions, all optional,: `<number-a><string-b><number-c><string-d>`. Numbers are base 10 integers, while stings are non-numeric ASCII characters.

In addition to the "normal" version numbers (e.g. `1.0`, `1.1.1alpha`, etc.), this means that something like the following is valid:

```
"version": "1alpha2beta.3gamma4delta.5epsilon6zeta.7eta8theta.9iota0kappa",
```

**Submitting to AMO:**
Every time you submit a new version to AMO, it must have a different version than any which you have previously submitted. I don't recall if AMO enforces that the version number be higher than the previous versions.  However, if the new version is not higher than the old versions, your users will not be automatically updated to the new version.